# Activities and WebViews

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm creating an app with a number of `WebView`'s. I'm doing this so when a user presses a menu button and and then presses the old menu button again, the state of the web page is saved and not reloaded, which it would be by loading the URL into only one `WebView`.

I just wanted some advice, should all of the `WebView`'s be in the same activity? I've read the API docs on activities but I'm not entirely sure what they're for, an easy clarification would be great.

Comment: I'd advice you to start doing some simple android application with a 2-3 activities which links to eachother, so you get the hang of it. Instead of starting on the 10th step with lots of activities and lots of webviews. But that's just my advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont fear creating new activity's for each screen. Activity is optimized for use on Android. Its a misconception that java developers use and avoid using activity's. Dont fear them. That said, if you are sure that you have just display webview's than you are better off using just one activity.